# Formulario - Excel

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, android, firebase

Estoy realizando un proyecto donde tengo un formulario, la información que tengo en ese formulario quiero vaciarla a un excel.La información la estoy almacenando a una base de datos Podrían ayudarme por favor?

Comment: ¿ayudarte en qué parte?, lee [ask] por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)

Es una libreria para trabajar archivos excel, solamente tienes que usar "DataTable"

```
XLWorkbook excelFile = new XLWorkbook();
DataTable table = GetData();
excelFile.Worksheets.Add(table);
excelFile.SaveAs("test.xlsx");
```

Comment: gracias por el aporte, me sirvió de mucho!

Comment: marcala como respuesta pls